# ROWNUMBER function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions, row-number

**Little explanation:**

I have a table called `passes` and it's linked with 2 tables (`services` (cod_serv) and `atend` (pass)). Passes can be duplicated for different services.

Eg.: If I have 3 services, I can have 3 passes nº 01, **BUT** not 2 passes nº 1 for the same service (I defined it in my composite primary key).

For tests, I added 102 passes (all with situation = "F" and with the same date (today)). Then I added **34** passes for each service (I have 3 services).

The following query is to show how the `schema` more or less defined.

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.pass, s.data, cod_serv, situation, hour, min
FROM passes 
JOIN atend a ON s.pass = a.pass;

PASS       DATA       COD_SERV       S      HOUR           MIN
-----      --------   ---------      -      -------        -------
04         26/03/16   2              F      12             24
04         26/03/16   1              F      13             27
13         26/03/16   1              F      14             26
18         26/03/16   3              F      14             27
18         26/03/16   2              F      14             28
15         26/03/16   1              F      14             29
10         26/03/16   3              F      14             30
...        ...        ...            ...    ...            ...
```

Then, I want to get the 100th (`ROWNUMBER()`) pass (as it's showing below it's 21) from a specific date with the situation = 'F' ordering by hour and min.

**Row Number 100:**

```
21         26/03/16   3              F      14             34
```

The following `query` is returning nothing and I can't figure out why. By the way, I have more than 100 passes with this situation.

```
SELECT DISTINCT pass, data, cod_serv, situation FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT a.pass, s.data, cod_serv, situation,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY situation, hour, min
                            ORDER BY situation, hour, min) row
   FROM passes s
   JOIN atend a ON s.pass = a.pass
   WHERE situation = 'F' AND
         TRUNC(a.data) = TRUNC('some date'))
WHERE row = 100;
```

**EDIT:**

My query at the moment:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pass, cod_serv FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT s.pass, cod_serv,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TRUNC(s.data)
                            ORDER BY a.hour, a.min) row
   FROM passes s
   JOIN atend a ON s.pass = a.pass
   WHERE s.situation = 'F' AND
         TRUNC(s.data) = TRUNC(SYSDATE))
WHERE row = 100;
```

Comment: you want `(partition by data order by hour, min)`

Comment: all rows will have the same value for situation anyway (because of `situacao = 'F'`) so there is no need to include it in the window definition or the order by

Comment: Got it, you're right, but it's still returning 0 rows.

Comment: When you run the inner `select`, are there any rows with a `row` of 100?  I assume not.  You'd need to show us what the inner query is returning and what you want it to return.  The data that you posted, for example, has only one row per day in `data`.  If your real table doesn't have 100 rows with the same `data` and a `situation` of `F`, the `where` clause in your inner `select` will filter the data set down to less than 100 rows so `row_number` will never return a value of 100.

Comment: Yes, there is a `row` with a `rownumber` 100. Another thing: I have 102 registries of passes and even with DISTINCT the inner `select` is returning me 306 rows (3x), why? By the way, as I mentioned, yes I have more than 100 registries with same date and with `situation` = 'F' (for test). I added some more code in the question.

Comment: @JustinCave do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the same fields in `PARTITION BY` and  `ORDER BY` in an `OVER` clause makes little sense.

The `PARTITION BY` clause should list the fields that define the group in which you start counting records from 1.

The `ORDER BY` clause defines the order in which records are counted within that group.

As you write:

> I want to get the 100th (`ROWNUMBER()`) pass from a specific date with the situation = 'F' ordering by hour and min

... you actually say in words what needs to be put in these clauses:

```
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY data, situation ORDER BY hour, min)
```

So your main mistake was to put *hour* and *min* in the `PARTITION BY` clause, making the record count starting from 1 as soon as a minute difference was found, giving most of your records the number 1.

**Edit**

It seems that Oracle does not retain the same `row` number when it is not selected. This is probably because the `ORDER BY hour, min` is not deterministic. Whatever the reason, it can be solved by selecting the `row` in the outer query:

```
SELECT pass, row FROM ( ... etc ...) WHERE row = 100
```

If you only need the pass, you can wrap that query again:

```
SELECT pass FROM (
    SELECT pass, row FROM ( ... etc ...) WHERE row = 100
)
```

Comment: Thanks for you your support, but unfortunately it isn't work. But I think it's not working first of all because, as I mentioned in my last edit, the inner `select` is returning 3x the count of rows in `passes` table even with `DISTINCT`. So I must fix it first

Comment: It might be interesting also to look at the output of `SELECT data, count(*) FROM passes WHERE situation = 'F' GROUP BY data HAVING count(*) > 99` to see how many cases you have with 100+ rows.

Comment: I tested it. Count = 102 (it's correct, I updated all the situations to 'F').

Comment: I think I finally got it. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107427/discussion-between-developer033-and-trincot).

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

First, before doing `row_number()`, apply ALL of your filters (since you don't want to count the rows that you're going to filter out):

```
SELECT s.pass, s.data, cod_serv, s.situation, a.hour, a.min
FROM passes s
JOIN atend a ON s.pass = a.pass
WHERE s.situation = 'F' 
AND TRUNC(s.data) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

Now, wrap that in an outer query where you apply `row_number()`:

```
SELECT pass, data, cod_serv, situation, hour, min,
       rowseq=row_number() over (order by hour, min)
FROM (
    SELECT s.pass, s.data, cod_serv, s.situation, a.hour, a.min
    FROM passes s
    JOIN atend a ON s.pass = a.pass
    WHERE s.situation = 'F' 
    AND TRUNC(s.data) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
) t1
```

Finally, wrap that in an outer query where you apply the filter for the "hundredth" record:

```
SELECT pass, data, cod_serv, situation, hour, min
FROM (
    SELECT pass, data, cod_serv, situation, hour, min,
           rowseq=row_number() over (order by hour, min)
    FROM (
        SELECT s.pass, s.data, cod_serv, s.situation, a.hour, a.min
        FROM passes s
        JOIN atend a ON s.pass = a.pass
        WHERE s.situation = 'F' 
        AND TRUNC(s.data) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
    ) t1
WHERE rowseq = 100
```

Lastly, if any parts need adjusting (different filters, joins, etc.), you can run each of these levels of inner queries on their own to check your intermediate results to make sure your *final* result is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but it gives me error: `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`